# El condicional vs el subjuntivo en una cláusula subordinada: consideraciones del tiempo

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Entiendo los usos del condicional bien, pero --de repente-- me parecía raro la 'atemporalidad' del condicional en una cláusula subordinada.  Es decir, el hecho de que el tiempo del subjuntivo en una cláusula subordinada tuviera que concordar con el de la cláusula principal

```
Jorge no cree que eso esté bien

Jorge no creía que eso estuviera bien
```

pero con el condicional no fuera así

```
Jorge cree que eso estaría bien

Jorge creía que esto estaría bien
```

Es muy probable que esté buscando tres pies al gato, o que esté mezclando usos distintos del condicional (hipótesis, 'futuro del pasado', etc), pero ¿el condicional es, de alguna manera, atemporal? ¿Cómo se distingue el uso del subjuntivo del condicional en una cláusula subordinada?

He indagado el tema, pero solo he podido encontrar una cosa, donde [Butt](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/new-reference-grammar-modern-spanish-4th-edition-john-butt-john-butt-carmen-benjamin/10.4324/9780203783467), 14.7, dice que

> For the purpose of agreement, the conditional counts as a past tense
> so the subjunctive in a subordinate clause governed by the conditional
> must also be in the past

Creo que solo quiere dar una explicación por el uso del imperfecto de subjuntivo con el condicional, es decir, comentar la concordancia, como dice.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la respuesta a la pregunta está en la propia pregunta, donde se habla de "usos distintos del condicional (hipótesis, 'futuro del pasado', etc)".

En la oración:

- Jorge cree que eso estaría bien.

la forma "estaría" describe un presente o futuro hipotético, o tentativo (no categórico). La oración precedente contrasta con:

- Jorge cree que eso está bien.
- Jorge cree que eso estará bien.

En cambio, en la oración:

- Jorge creía que esto estaría bien.

la forma "estaría" expresa futuro desde una perspectiva pasada. Sería la forma en estilo indirecto de:

Jorge: Creo que esto estará bien => Jorge creía (en ese momento en el pasado) que esto estaría bien (en el futuro).